# TestFlight development and production

Tags: ios, icloud, cloudkit

If I develop an app and place it on TestFlight that uses CloudKit will all the people using the app be logged into MY Icloud, or will they use their own? If they use mine it should work but if they use their own I will need to change the code to create the tables I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudKit only uses each individual user's iCloud account.

But there are two parts - the public and the private databases.

The public databases go against your usage allotment. The private databases go against the user's own allotment.

Either way, you don't need to change code to create the tables. You need to use the CloudKit dashboard to move your schemas to production.

This is all documented in the [CloudKit Quick Start](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014987).

Comment: So I created the tables I need in the development server and moved them over to the production server and  now I can log in and everything works. When a new user logs in and runs the app they will copy the tables I have on my production server to their tables in order for the app to work? Thanks for the link, I will do some more reading:)